# What is the name of the ./... special path?

Tags: go, path

When I use golang, I can write:

```
go test ./...
```

which tells go to run all the tests found under the `.` directory.

What is the name of the `./...` special path?

Also, is there support for that special path by other projects/tools or is it specific to golang?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no name for the `./...`pattern, but the output of `go help packages` refers to `...` as a _wildcard_ for import-path patterns.

Comment: Ah! It's similar to `*` only it also matches `/`. I had not thought about it that way. That makes sense and the name `wildcard` makes sense too.